# Webpack does not find module vscode when building jupyterlab with custom extension

Tags: typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to build a LSP (Language Server Protocol) extension for jupyter lab, using the vscode-languageclient library for typescript. The vscode-languageclient module seems to be recognized correctly, however it is dependent on the vscode module, which webpack does not find when building jupyter lab.

I have added the vscode module to my extension using

`jlpm add vscode`

To get `jlpm build` to work, i had to add the following to my package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "postinstall": "node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/install"
}
"engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.33.x"
}
```

This made it possible for jlpm to build the extension, however when running `jupyter lab build` I get a webpack error about it not being able to locate the module vscode (see terminal output).

I have tried adding this to my webpack.config.js file in the staging directory of jupyter lab before running `jupyter lab build`:

```
module.exports {
...
  resolve: {
      alias: {
          vscode$: path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/vscode")
      }
  }
}
```

However, it did not change the error.

These are the import statements I use in my index.ts file:

```
import { workspace} from 'vscode';

import {
  LanguageClient,
  LanguageClientOptions,
  ServerOptions,
  TransportKind
} from 'vscode-languageclient';
```

This is the output of running `jupyter lab build`:

```
~$ sudo jupyter lab build
[LabBuildApp] JupyterLab 0.35.5
[LabBuildApp] Cleaning /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab
Cleaning /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab...
Success!
[LabBuildApp] Building in /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab
[LabBuildApp] Node v8.10.0

[LabBuildApp] > /usr/bin/npm pack /home/russell/Uni/FP/Jupy.LSP
Jupy-LSP-0.1.0.tgz
[LabBuildApp] > node /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterlab/staging/yarn.js install
yarn install v1.9.4
info No lockfile found.
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
warning @jupyterlab/application > @jupyterlab/apputils > react > fbjs > core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.5 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
warning css-loader > cssnano > autoprefixer > browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
warning css-loader > cssnano > postcss-merge-rules > browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
warning css-loader > cssnano > postcss-merge-rules > caniuse-api > browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
warning css-loader > cssnano > postcss-merge-rules > postcss-selector-parser > flatten@1.0.2: I wrote this module a very long time ago; you should use something else.
[3/5] Fetching packages...
warning Jupy-LSP@0.1.0: The engine "vscode" appears to be invalid.
warning vscode-languageclient@5.2.1: The engine "vscode" appears to be invalid.
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[4/5] Linking dependencies...
warning "@jupyterlab/vdom-extension > @nteract/transform-vdom@1.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.6.1".
warning "@jupyterlab/vega4-extension > vega-embed > vega-themes@2.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "vega@*".
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
[3/3] ⡀ Jupy-LSP
[-/3] ⡀ waiting...
error /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/Jupy-LSP: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/install
Arguments: 
Directory: /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/Jupy-LSP
Output:
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/Jupy-LSP/node_modules/vscode/bin/install'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)


[LabBuildApp] > node /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterlab/staging/yarn.js run build
yarn run v1.9.4
$ webpack
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vscode' in '/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/Jupy-LSP/lib'
    at factory.create (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:535:10)
    at factory (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:397:22)
    at resolver (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21)
    at asyncLib.parallel (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22)
    at /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
    at /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6877:13
    at normalResolver.resolve (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25)
    at doResolve (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:184:12)
    at hook.callAsync (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:37:5)
    at hook.callAsync (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at hook.callAsync (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:42:38)
    at hook.callAsync (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn41 (eval at create (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:28:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/ModuleKindPlugin.js:23:37)
    at hook.callAsync (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at hook.callAsync (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at args (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:30:14)
    at hook.callAsync (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:37:5)
    at hook.callAsync (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at hook.callAsync (/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
resolve 'vscode' in '/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/Jupy-LSP/lib'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/Jupy-LSP/package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/Jupy-LSP/lib/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /usr/local/share/jupyter/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /usr/local/share/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /usr/local/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /usr/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/Jupy-LSP/node_modules
        using description file: /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/Jupy-LSP/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      looking for modules in /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules
        using description file: /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vscode/package.json (relative path: .)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/Jupy-LSP/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/vscode)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vscode is not a file
            .wasm
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/Jupy-LSP/node_modules/vscode doesn't exist
            .wasm
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vscode.wasm doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/Jupy-LSP/node_modules/vscode.wasm doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vscode.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/Jupy-LSP/node_modules/vscode.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vscode.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/Jupy-LSP/node_modules/vscode.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vscode.json doesn't exist
              /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/Jupy-LSP/node_modules/vscode.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/Jupy-LSP/node_modules/vscode doesn't exist
            as directory
              existing directory
                using path: /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vscode/index
                  using description file: /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vscode/package.json (relative path: ./index)
                    no extension
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vscode/index doesn't exist
                    .wasm
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vscode/index.wasm doesn't exist
                    .mjs
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vscode/index.mjs doesn't exist
                    .js
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vscode/index.js doesn't exist
                    .json
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vscode/index.json doesn't exist
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Note that this error disappears when removing the postinstall call from my package.json:

```
error /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/Jupy-LSP: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/install
Arguments: 
Directory: /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/Jupy-LSP
Output:
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/Jupy-LSP/node_modules/vscode/bin/install'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
```

Unfortunately, this does not remove/change the subsequent error message.

UPDATE: Solutions I have tried (but didn't work):

- Changing the postinstall call to
  `"postinstall": "node /usr/local/lib/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vscode/bin/install"`
  The first error when building jupyter disappears again, but webpack still doesn't find vscode
- Cloning the [official vscode repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode) into node modules and using that instead
  The Typescript compiler doesn't find the module, even after renaming it to vscode in its package.json. This doesn't seem like it would be an intended (or stable) solution anyway.
- Using the [monaco-languageclient](https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient)
  The monaco-languageclient is dependent on the vscode-languageclient and therefore doesn't work either
- Running the vscode Compile binary in the node module
  This gives the following output

```
$ node bin/compile 
The vscode extension module got updated to TypeScript 2.0.x.
Please see https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_6#_extension-authoring for instruction on how to migrate your extension.
```

However, the link doesn't actually adress how to upgrade vscode but rather which new modules to include.

On another note, I've searched the whole vscode folder for acutal code contents and could only find these three files:
`shared.js  testrunner.d.ts  testrunner.js`, which contain 42, 44 and 125 LoC. I am not sure why the vscode module provides no functionality, but this seems to be the core of the problem.